# R or Excel: Calculate difference between dates

Tags: programming, excel

I have a list of course completion dates (person, start, end) in the following format (exemplary):

Person X || Sept 21, 2021 06:30 PM || Sept 21, 2021 06:50 PM

Now I'd like to calculate the overall spent time in minutes from the difference between end and start date. However, I struggle with formatting the start and end date in a way that allows such difference calculations. Excel does not seem to provide a date format that suits the given table record. Manual formatting would take ages since the table is pretty long.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The function(s) you‘re looking for in R are „date parsing“ functions. There are various libraries out there which do that.

```
as.POSIXct()
```

should to the trick out of the box.

You will need to use `strptime` format codes for your dates.